# Is there any way i can delete complete spread sheet via api using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I have google spreadsheet id of spreadsheet that I have created from python but I just can't find any way to delete that file from python API
[i am using code from here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/sheets/snippets/spreadsheet_snippets.py)

"i am expecting a method to pass spreadSheetId which will delete spread sheet containing that id"

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about it? Do you want to delete the Spreadsheet? Or do you want to delete one of sheet in the Spreadsheet? Do you want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with Python?

Comment: I want to delete the whole spreadsheet by giving spreadsheet id and yes I will prefer a way to do this via google spreadsheet client using python but any other way could be helpful am surprise that I cannot delete the very thing I have created via API, I may use gspread library but I will be needing to rework all other crud operation that i have integrated with odoo so, for now, I am looking for doing it via simple googleapiclient

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to delete the Spreadsheet, how about using [the method of Files: delete of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)? In this case, google-api-python-client can be used.

Comment: thanks for helping I think I got it, I am using this guide to get things done [google spreadsheet guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) 
 I think I only have integrated google spreadsheet not google drive to delete the file I need to integrate with google drive this may work for me I will try it, I guess only integrating with sheet will not help in deleting but when they ask us to allow I was notified that sheet will be able to delete, create and edit

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the help that worked for me, I have another question, can we get spreadsheet data located in the shared drive, I am getting this error `'"This operation is not supported for this document"` this link also didn't helped much [google drive docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives) I have given owner rights but still no effect

Comment: Ok i will and thank

Answer (score 0):

```
# Authentication to Google Sheet API & Google Drive API
scopes = [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", 
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
          ]


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(my_secret_file, scopes=scopes)
sheets_service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

# Now delete. We only need the drive_service
drive_service.files().delete(fileId='your spreadsheet id').execute()
```